# How to be notified when foreground (top) activity (application) changes

Tags: android, service, android-activity, foreground

I want to write a service for Android platform that is notified when the current foreground activity changes.
Basically the service should do some tasks only when the top activity changes.
Is there any way to subscribe  and to be notified when this kind of event occurs ? 
Or there is no possibility and the service should poll from time to time the list of running activities and to check what is the foreground activity ?Not preferable solution...

Comment: On what platform are your trying to write your service ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: Did you look into the logcat output? I assume the ActivityManager is always involved when foreground activity changes, so this might be visible from the log.

Comment: @Alex Did you ever get to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there are two ways to do that.

1. Start a service and monitor the Activity Stack, you might check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20740784/4506191)
2. Use an Accessibility Service, you could find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27642535/4506191)

Comment: Note that the linked technique for polling for the current activity doesn't work in Android 5+.

Comment: @Sam Then how the application that protects selected application work? How they detect when an application comes and foreground? Thank you

Comment: @Astrount, I don't know what developers use these days, but the last time  I checked, option 2 in this answer still works in Android 5.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind every activity to the service and you will know which activity is running.

try this:

```
List runningTaskInfos=actvityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(i).topActivity .getPackageName();
```

this method will give info of activity's package name which is in foreground..............

Comment: Well this is not a solution, maybe I've expressed myself wrong, I want that the service be notified what application is running in the foreground (it could be any of the installed applications) and compare with a predefined list of applications and if it is on the list to do some work.

Comment: Ah ok, you wrote Activity so I understood that it was only one application. I really don't know how to do what you want to do sorry

Comment: @Alex, you can use this technique to do that, but you need to poll.