# How do I notify the "current" activity from a service or an alarm?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, notifications

I am making an app that has 2 activities a service and an alarm.

How can I find the "current activity" from the service or the alarm ?

A) IE replace 
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RatActivity.class);
with 
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, "CurrenActivity.class");

B)
If an activity is visible tell it to look at a database if not visible put up a notification.

I have looked around quite a bit (including docs) and I still can't figure out.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This has pretty much been covered in [Android: How can I get the current foreground activity (from a service)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/android-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-from-a-service)

However, it might be simplest to toggle a value in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) within the Activity [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29)/[onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) callbacks. See the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) docs for more info, specifically so you can cater for unexpected Activity termination.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: The shared preferences pattern is what I was looking for. Excellent answer -thanks.