# NetworkReceiver never called after changes to Network State

Tags: android, android-networking

To conserver battery in my application, whenever my app needs to sync with the cloud, I first check if the network is available. If no connection is available, I register a network broadcast receiver as follows. But this never gets called.

I'm testing this by putting the device into airplane mode. I see the "Network Receiver ENABLED" message. But after I disable airplane mode, and after my Wifi connects, I expect to see the "Received Network Change Intent" message, and it never appears.

Can anyone point out what I may be doing wrong?

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
networkReceiver = new NetworkReceiver();
registerReceiver(networkReceiver, filter);
Log.d(TAG, "Network Receiver ENABLED");
```

This is the NetworkReceiver:

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static String TAG = NetworkReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context_, Intent intent_) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received Network Change Intent");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you declare permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
</uses-permission> in your manifest?

Comment: yes, that permission is present.

Comment: These two answers helped me out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624470/enable-and-disable-a-broadcast-receiver

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374071/delay-service-action-until-network-connection-is-available

Answer (score 0):

You can try below option.

1. Set Network Access Permission if you haven't declare in manifest file: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>`.
2. Register Receiver using context: 
   Instead of `registerReceiver(networkReceiver, filter);` use `getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(networkReceiver, filter);`