# Persisting BroadcastReceiver reference

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

What I want to achieve is to give user a button saying 'Start broadcast receiving' and another one saying 'Stop broadcast receiving'.

I'm registering BroadcastReceiver for "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" intent ('Start broadcast receiving' functionality):

```
incomingSmsReceiver = new IncomingSmsReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(incomingSmsReceiver, filter);
```

Then I'm using *unregisterReceiver()* for 'Stop broadcast receiving':

```
getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(incomingSmsReceiver);
```

As you can see it's using the same reference (`private static BroadcastReceiver incomingSmsReceiver;`).

**The problem is:**

This works fine as long as my app's process is not terminated. When user click 'Start receiving broadcast' and after that my app is been killed by Android I'm loosing `incomingSmsReceiver` reference (when I run my app next time it's set to `null` by default). There's no way for user to stop receiving broadcast as the reference is lost.

**How to persist this reference?** And how to make it possible to call `getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(incomingSmsReceiver);` after recreating app's process by Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found better solution for such problem: [Enable and disable a Broadcast Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624470/enable-and-disable-a-broadcast-receiver) (CommonsWare's answer).

The solution is to register BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest file. Then to use [PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int%29) to enable / disable this component.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you don't need to hold on to the exact same BroadcastReciever reference. Create a new reference in the exact same way in which you would create one normally and pass it to `unregisterService`.

Comment: But there's nothing to do with Intents in `public abstract void unregisterReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver)` method. It only gets a BroadcastReceiver reference.

Comment: @ricewind: Updated the answer! Sorry for the mistakes.