# android text receiver issue

Tags: android, text

I created a text listener like this (below) in the manifest file. I assume the listener will always be enabled in any activity (thus wasting battery).

```
    <receiver 
      android:name="com.me.basic.SMSReceiverActivity"
      android:enabled="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But in my app, there are lots of activities, and only one of them requires the text listening to be on. Is there a code I can use to disable and enable this listener?

Comment: Have you tried this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624470/enable-and-disable-a-broadcast-receiver ?

Comment: @user387184 , i took a look at it, but I don't understand it still...

Comment: I would expect CommonsWare's solution to work for you by just replacing the onBootReceiver with your onSMSReceiver class

Comment: i'm getting a variable not found error on 'prefs', 'key' and 'EditPreferences'. What do I replace for these?