# Retrieve instance of a registered BroadcastReceiver to unregister

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

in my app I have 2 `BroadcastReceivers`. Lets call the `AReceiver` and `BReceiver`. `AReceiver` is just listening for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` so it can register `BReceiver`for a different action, if its turned on in the settings of my app.

So I have a `PreferenceActivity` that can switch the status of my app, which means:

- Status: On

  - `AReceiver` will **not** register `BReceiver` at boot
  - Changing from Off -> On should register `BReceiver`
- Status: Off

  - `AReceiver` will register `BReceiver` at boot
  - Changing from On -> Off should unregister `BReceiver`

Here is the problem I'm having. How can I unregister `BReceiver` if it was either registered in `AReceiver` or in the `PreferenceActivity`, which could have been closed in the meanwhile? I don't know what I have to pass to `unregisterBroadcastReceiver()` as an argument, since it wants the instance of the registered receiver.

**How do I retrieve the instance of a registered `BroadcastReceiver` so I can unregister it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to put the BReceiver in the manifest (default disabled) and then enable and disable it at any time. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624470/enable-and-disable-a-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the `enabled` state of a receiver in the manifest, but I thought I'd still have to unregister it. You shall not assume :/ Actually using this I only have to switch the state when the preference is changed, therefore rendering `AReceiver` useless, as I can put the `IntentFilter` into the manifest as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can make that activation of BReceiver is always done via AReceiver (even when switching OFF->ON in preferences). So that AReceiver stores the instance of BReceiver and is able to unregister it. Does it make sense ?

Comment: If i unterstood you right, you meant I should store the instance of `Breceiver` in `AReceiver`. If so, I don't think this would have worked, since the life time of a `BroadcastReceiver` instance is limited to the onReceive. So the instance which regeistered the `BReceiver` at boot would not have been the same, as the one that would have been used from the settings later on.

Comment: Yes you're totally right. Go for @iLRedEiMAtTi's solution then :)