# Disable my app on startup and load android usually

Tags: android

I have created app which is also a launcher. This app will load app by default on start up. I would like to give user an option to uncheck not run app on startup.

To load the app on start up I am using Boot receiver in manifest and calling the required java file to load the app.

Now How do I override startup if option is unchecked - instead of loading my app it should load the home screen?

Tried this:

```
  public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
  {
 String nostartup= "2";
 @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
    if (nostartup.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
    {

    Intent i = new Intent(context, main.class);  
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);  
    }
    else
    {

    }   
  }
  }
```

When I restart my tablet I get complete action using prompt gives out other launcher programs with home laucher

How do I go about choosing home launcher?

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5625179/906362

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable and disable a Broadcast Receiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624470/enable-and-disable-a-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: "To load the app on start up I am using Boot receiver in manifest and calling the required java file to load the app" -- that will not be reliable, as you have no control over when your `BroadcastReceiver` gets control, and so the home screen might still appear on top.

Comment: This setup works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the receiver you should check the option.

if its enabled, start your app/activity.
if not, just do nothing. and it should go to the homescreen.

Comment: It is not going to homescreen instead it is giving complete launcher using prompt? How do I fix this?