# unregister broadcast receiver registered through manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

Is it possible to unregister a `BroadcastReceiver` that has been registered through manifest?
Also please let me know if it possible to ignore the `BroadcastReceiver`, without making any code changes, as this `BroadcastReceiver` is of no use to me now. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can enable and disable it on the Manifest and programmatically enable and disable it as well...see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624470/enable-and-disable-a-broadcast-receiver

Comment: yes you can use `getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting` for enabling or disabling broadcast receiver at runtime see [Enable and disable a Broadcast Receiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624470/enable-and-disable-a-broadcast-receiver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable Receiver with this code:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
   ComponentName compName = 
        new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
            MyReceiver.class);
   pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        compName,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Also you can use `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED` to enable Receiver.

Comment: can we also disable it programatically, using unregister recevicer?