# Monitoring wifi state change since boot time in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, wifimanager

I want to *perform certain network actions* when a specific wifi network is connected, and this has to be done automatically without user input even since boot time. There is also a `Preference` that tells me whether or not these actions are performed automatically.

As far as I have understood, applications need the special permission named `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` to perform certain actions at boot time (including initializing the application itself), and those are implemented in the code via a `BroadcastReceiver`.

In order to save battery avoiding polling for wifi state, I can register a `BroadcastReceiver` for the `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` and query it for the wifi network's name.

Can the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` listener, or just any other listener, be declared from `AndroidManifest.xml` and be triggered **without application start**, just like making boot receiver useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can respond to `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` via a manifest-registered receiver. There are a few broadcasts where you cannot (e.g., `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`). This would eliminate your need to get control at boot time.

You can [enable and disable that receiver based on the preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624470/enable-and-disable-a-broadcast-receiver/5625179#5625179), so you do not get control when it is not needed.

Comment: but how to register a receiver in manifest to get notified about connectivity_action ? (like change in connectivity e.g. wifi/network availability)

Comment: @MehulJoisar: Use `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`, as the OP and my answer mention: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Comment: yeah,I know that,but I am not able to find that constant intent in manifest, please have a look at http://www.imagebam.com/image/2c43b5247964554

Comment: @MehulJoisar: If you read the JavaDocs that I linked to, you will find that the value is `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`. There are gaps in the auto-complete that the ADT adds Eclipse.