# Cannot Disable Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I got the logic for disable/enable broadcast receiver from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5625179/1289480).

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean checked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v == disableBlock) {
            manageBlockSetting(checked);
        }
    }

private void manageBlockSetting(boolean disable) {
        Log.e(tag, "Disable : " + disable);
        int flag = disable ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED
                : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(SettingActivity.this, PhoneCallReceiver.class);

        getApplication().getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, flag, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        editSharedPreferences(StoreConstantValue.SETTING_DISABLE_BLOCK, disable);
}
```

And in Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.vsmart.unocaller.blockingservice.PhoneCallReceiver" 
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

When I deploy with `android:enabled="false"`

I can enable it once. But when I want to disable. Nothing happens, I can't disable it. It is still block incoming calls.

My device is Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 2.3.3

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declare the receiver in manifest you can try registering/unregistering it from code. For example

```
private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

    }
}


private MyPhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
```

To enable

```
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

And to disable

```
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

where

```
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```