# Crash while self updating APK (component class does not exist)

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-install-apk, android-broadcastreceiver

I am working on a system application which updates itslef by downloading an apk and installing it by using PackageManager's `installPackage()` method.

I am getting the following exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class com.myapp.package.receivers.SomeOldReceiver does not exist in com.myapp.package
           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1544)
           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
           at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.setComponentEnabledSetting(IPackageManager.java:3420)
           at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1492)
           at com.myapp.package.utils.AndroidUtils.enableDisableComponent(SourceFile:113)
           at ...
```

The "SomeOldReceiver" component does not exist in the updated apk.

It seems like the "old" code from the existing APK is executed (its application's onCreate() is invoked) trying to access the "new" manifest that exists in the updated APK and can't find the "old" receiver (is this even possible?).

My app also listens to PACAKGE_ADDED & PACKAGE_REMOVED intents.

This crash happens on a relatively large percentage of users.

Any suggestion or clue as to why this bug is happening and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When do you get the exception? when does the code `com.myapp.package.utils.AndroidUtils.enableDisableComponent` run?

Comment: `This crash happens on a relatively large percentage of users.` kind of makes me suspect it's due to the API incompatibility that occurred as the installPackage signature modified and/or the whole PackageManager region between platforms. It might be worth it to drop the PackageManager idea and return to the intent way?

Comment: Do you able to see starting which Android version this crash happens?

Comment: @Geralt_Encore:  yes. it's always from android 5.0.2

Comment: Maybe cached (compiled) code is not invalidated automatically? Since application is running when package updating, native image is locked and isn't removed. When package installed, system tries to launch it to process broadcast, launches old native image and, obviously, catches an exception.

Comment: Do you have services running with START_STICKY or broadcast receivers either registered or listed in the (old) manifest that might be triggered by the update?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways how to update APK..Im not sure which one you are using.. I faced similar issue .. and it was due to app has multiple instances during updating.. you can make app as single instance or just be sure there are not old instances running. I hope that may help.

Comment: how can I make an app to run as a single instance?

Comment: in manifest  set android:launchMode="singleInstance" to your main activity

Comment: I don't think that setting launch mode for an activity affects application multiple instances vs single instance,  it's affects only activity.   either way - for the manner of speak:  my application starts and updates itself without any activity ever been launcher at all

Answer (score 0):

[Since JELLY_BEAN version](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html):
Calls to `PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting` will now throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the given component class name does not exist in the application's manifest.

It explains why this crash happens on a large percentage of users.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannot confirm whether this would be of any help since I haven't tested it myself.

Maybe you can try disabling your "SomeOldReceiver" (or any other components that might be triggered by the installation of the new package) by making a call to [`setComponentEnabledSetting()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5625179/1023092) before calling `installPackage()` ?

Logistically, this might require you to produce an interim version of your app (that added the `setComponentEnabledSetting()` call before `installPackage()` and should still have "SomeOldReceiver" in its manifest) to update the old version first. You can then update this version to your real updated version with "SomeOldReceiver" removed.