# How to get current on screen activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How can I get the current foreground activity (from a service)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/android-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-from-a-service)

In a method I have to know which activity is on the screen. How do I get the current activity?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? Where is that method located ? What do you want to archive?

Comment: getParent().getActivity() will do the work. This is what i can guess so far.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes Fragments need to know which Activity they belong to. For this, use [Fragment.getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29). This works since API 11.[Refer this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity/)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the current activity

You don't. There may not be a "current activity".

Comment: Even if there might not be a current activity, it would be nice to be able to determine if there was once or not. What I'd like to be able to determine is which of my activities is active, if any.