# Get the name or package name of the currently focused/running application(android)

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How can I get current opened application name on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118721/android-how-can-i-get-current-opened-application-name-on-screen)

I am developing small android application.In my application I am displaying list of all install application.Now what I want to do whenever user open other application, check whether that application name present in my list or not.

For this I need to implement a background service or broadcast receiver kind of functionality which continuously listening launch or resume of other application.I know such kind of functionality are considered as malicious activity.But lot of other application like task killer, app security lock doing such thing.

Is there any way to implement such kind of functionality. Need Help...... Thank you....

Comment: check this http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/getting-info-about-your-currently-running-activities/

Comment: Thank you Eric and Ram Kiran for quick reply.. I tried this, Its working fine it gives me all running task info. But What I want to do is When user open any other application, in background get the name of that application or package-name (continuously checking not only when I open my application).