# Checking which app is on the screen

Tags: android, service

Is there a way to detect when an app is going into pause state or checking which app is currently displayed or running on the screen?

I know I can get a list of running apps but I want to know when an app(not my app) is going into pause state or which is app is displayed on the screen.

Regards

Comment: try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118721/android-how-can-i-get-current-opened-application-name-on-screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5528441/1393623

Comment: Is there a way to detect when other apps are going into pause sttate?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to check continuously start background thread.

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable _runnable;

private void startThread() {
    handler=new Handler();
    _runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            checkRunningApplications();
            handler.postDelayed(_runnable, 500);
        }
    };
    _runnable.run();
}

private void checkRunningApplications() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
    RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = runningTasks.get(0);
    ComponentName topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity;
    System.out.println(topActivity.getPackageName());
}
```

Mention below permission in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```