# Stop background music when user closes the app, not when user changes activity

Tags: android

I'm studying how to develop android app. I started with a very simple app with only one activity. Then I added a service to play background music; of course i used the method onPause(), onStop() onDestroy() to manage the service.

But now, that i have another activity, the background music stops when the new activity is opened (because  the method onPause() is called).

I want to stop the background music only when user closes or destroys my entire app, not when user passes from an activity to another.

Probably i made a big mistake when i started building my app. Now i 'm trying to solve this problem.

I tried to use also bindService, but i still have the same problem.

How should i menage this issue?

Comment: Users do not stop apps.  Android does.  gabrielaugustodm is right.

Answer (score 0):

To play the music I think is better you use a Android [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use. Each service class must have a corresponding
>    declaration in its package's AndroidManifest.xml. Services
>   can be started with Context.startService() and Context.bindService().
>
> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is
>   going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such
>   as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to
>   do that work. More information on this can be found in Processes and
>   Threads. The IntentService class is available as a standard
>   implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules
>   its work to be done.

Comment: I'm using a service to play background music

Comment: I didn't get what you are suggesting to do :(

Answer (score 0):

From your service, you can periodically check what the foreground activity(or package) is using the method [found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753333/752320). If it doesn't belong to you, you can kill the service.