# Is there a system broadcast for top activity changes?

Tags: android

I want to listen to an event that if a certain activity is on top. Is there a system broadcast or event listener to support that?

Answer (score 0):

If this yours activity, you can send a broadcast yourself at onStart().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could [start a service to monitor the Activity Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740440/how-to-check-the-top-activity-from-android-app-in-background-service/20740784#20740784) or you could [use an Accessibility Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/android-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-from-a-service/27642535#27642535) to achieve that.