# Android app start and end event

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app which track user activity on app which include time etc, Now if user has opened the app, It will start an session and till user in this app , his session will continue, He can switch to multiple activity. Now meantime he switches to another app, His session logging should be stopped and written down to file

What I tried

I created one base activity and 
On resume event if counter is zero, I start session and increment counter and 
On stop event , i decrement counter and if counter is zero, I stop session

But this will not calculate actual problem of tracking as android doesn't stop activity as user switch to another app.

So is there any way to achieve such thing.

Additional:

If we can get whether app activity is active on screen so event can be used to start or end session.

Answer (score 6):

I can think of two ways of doing it:

### Option 1:

You can create a service which scans for the current application on the foreground and see if it is your activity. Here is some code you can use, I took it from another answer:

> There's an easy way of getting a list of running tasks from the
>   ActivityManager service. You can request a maximum number of tasks
>   running on the phone, and by default, the currently active task is
>   returned first.
>
> Once you have that you can get a ComponentName object by requesting
>   the `topActivity` from your list.
>
> Here's an example.
>
> ```
> ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
>
>      // get the info from the currently running task
>      List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 
>
>      Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
>              + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
>
>      ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
>    componentInfo.getPackageName();
> ```
>
> You will need the following permission on your manifest:
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
> ```

Link to the answer: [Android: How can I get the current foreground activity (from a service)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/android-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-from-a-service)

You can call this every one second or less to detect if your app is still active. Please note that it is a deprecated and is not recommended for using for this kind of things, according to official documentation:

> getRunningTasks()
>
> Note: this method is only intended for debugging and presenting task
>   management user interfaces. This should never be used for core logic
>   in an application, such as deciding between different behaviors based
>   on the information found here. Such uses are not supported, and will
>   likely break in the future. For example, if multiple applications can
>   be actively running at the same time, assumptions made about the
>   meaning of the data here for purposes of control flow will be
>   incorrect.

---

### Option 2:

The second option is to create a class that extends `Application` with a flag, for example `isAppRunning`, which will be true or false according if your application is on the foreground or not:

```
public class MyAppContext extends Application {

   public boolean isAppRunning = true;

   public void setIsAppRunning(boolean v){
      isAppRunning = v;
   }

   public boolean isAppRunning(){
      return isAppRunning;
   }

}
```

Then on your `AndroidManifest.xml` you have to add this class so it will be used when your application starts. Just add `android:name=".MyAppContext"` under the application tag:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyAppContext"
```

Now in every activity that you have you should override `onResume()` and `onPause()` and set the flag to the corresponding value:

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((MyAppContext)getApplication()).setIsAppRunning(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        ((MyAppContext)getApplication()).setIsAppRunning(false);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

On this way every time you start an Activity the value of `isAppRunning` in `MyAppContext` will be `true`, when you exit the `Activity` it will be `false` but if another Activity opens (for example if you pressed the back button so you are returning to the previous activity) the value will be immediately `true` again.

When you finally finish all your Activities none of the `onResume()` methods will be called and all the `onPause()` methods will be called so `isAppRunning` will be `false` and you know your `Activity` is no longer on the foreground.

So resuming, if `isAppRunning` is `true` your application is on the foreground (start the session tracking) otherwise it's gone (stop the session tracking). You can create a `Timer` in `MyAppContext` class to check the value of `isAppRunning` periodically, so it would be:

```
public class MyAppContext extends Application {

   public boolean isAppRunning = true;
   public final int timerRate = 500;    // Execute timer task every 500mS

   public void setIsAppRunning(boolean v){
      isAppRunning = v;
   }

   public boolean isAppRunning(){
      return isAppRunning;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      Timer mTimer = new Timer();

      mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            if(isAppRunning) startSesionTracking();
            else stopSesionTracking();
         }
      }, 0, REFRESH_TIME);
   }

   private void startSesionTracking () { ... };
   private void stopSesionTracking () { ... };

}
```

You should modify `timerRate` according to the precision you want to get in your session tracking.

Comment: This is a deprecated API and doesn't always return the correct value. I am forced to use this in my app and it doesn't work all the time. The API docs clearly mentions that.

Comment: Yes, but I can't think of anything else to track an activity.

Answer (score 2):

Extend all your Activities from BaseActivity like below. This is the best option for you as onPause and onResume methods are guaranteed to be called whenever your Activities show up or go away from phone screen.

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Start Logging
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // End Logging
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest (and best) way to go at it, and also the recommended usage for most 3rd party APIs that require this (e.g. Flurry)

Answer (score 2):

1.Create a class named AppLifecycleTracker and paste this.

```
private class AppLifecycleTracker implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
            private int numStarted = 0;
            private String TAG = "AppLifecycleTracker";


            private int numOfCreated = 0;

            @Override`enter code here`
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
                if (numOfCreated == 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated: app started");
                }
                numOfCreated++;
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated: " + numOfCreated);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
                if (numStarted == 0) {
                    // app went to foreground
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityStarted: foreground");

                }
                numStarted++;


            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
                numStarted--;
                if (numStarted == 0) {
                    // app went to background
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityStarted: background");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
                numOfCreated--;
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityDestroyed: " + numOfCreated);
            }
        }
```

*** in onActivityCreate if numOfCreated = 0, then you can say app has started. 
*** in onActivityDestroyed if numOfCreated = 0, then you can say app is closed.

2. Create a class extending Application, in onCreate, add this line

   registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new AppLifecycleTracker());
3. set application name as the Application class in manifest.xml

Thats it. You are good to go.

Comment: Looks like there may be a risk of double decrement if an activity is both stopped and destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into Activity lifecycles on Android.

What you need is `onPause` - see the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

I would also mention that onPause is fired even when switching between multiple activities, so you'd need to track when it's pausing to go to another screen.

Comment: so using onPause will not give app information about whether is it switching to another app or another activity...

Comment: No, this is just a part of the way Activities work, it runs when the activity is no longer in focus. This happens when the user switches to another app, another app takes foreground focus (I noticed this happens if you add a word to the dictionary on the keyboard) and even when the device is locked by the user, or the screen-timeout locks the device.

Comment: The way I did this was to use an application-level variable, and just set it to true when you're switching to another activity in your app - you know this because you're using `startActivity(Intent intent)`. Reset it back to false in all the `onResume` methods in your activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by the source code below I mention which is also saved from orientation change . ([Reference](https://medium.com/@iamsadesh/android-how-to-detect-when-app-goes-background-foreground-fd5a4d331f8a))

```
public class ApplicationEventTracker implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
private int activityReferences = 0;
private boolean isActivityChangingConfigurations = false;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    if (++activityReferences == 1 && !isActivityChangingConfigurations) {
        // App enters foreground
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    isActivityChangingConfigurations = activity.isChangingConfigurations();
    if (--activityReferences == 0 && !isActivityChangingConfigurations) {
        // App enters background
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now Android provide Lifecycle observer. So you can use that. You can add observer in your application class to detect state of app. You can find more details in this link [What is lifecycle observer and how to use it correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369540/what-is-lifecycle-observer-and-how-to-use-it-correctly)

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements LifecycleObserver
        
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        
            ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
        
        }
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    public void appInResumeState() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"In Foreground",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    public void appInPauseState() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"In Background",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```