# Android application onExit event

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm newbee on android, and already read [Android app start and end event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134853/android-app-start-and-end-event) and [Android onClose event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785720/android-onclose-event) but haven't found the answer.

I'm developing a simple application -  flashlight.
And I want to release camera LED when application (**not activity**) is ended. Android has Application *onCreate* event, but doesn't have an appropriate *onEnd/onExit* event.
Activity *OnDestroy* event is not the case, because it is raised each time the device changes its orientation.

Does **Application** have *onEnd* event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Application have onEnd event?

No. Mostly, that is because applications do not "end". They are either in the foreground, in the background, or their processes are terminated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it:

You have a listener onPause()  that is triggered when your app goes in background.
And usually when you kill your app in the task manager...your app goes in background for a few sec.
And that is the only way I found to do this.
For my example I have an app that plays a music automatically at launch. (Even if mobile is in silent mode).

I use onPause() to stop music and set original volume back to silent.

```
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mp.pause(); //that is mediaplayer pause
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,originalVol, 0);
} //set volume to its original state
```