# How to get Application Lifecycle events in Activities?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app that can pop up a dialog any time the app returns from the background.

My app has multiple Activities and I've been trying to create a base class that checks for OnResume in the Activity.  The problem is, when I switch between Activities, they fire OnResume which is not what I want, I only want the dialog to appear when the app itself resumes from the background.

I see Jetpack has Application lifecycle events which looks like exactly what I'm looking for in **ProcessLifecycleOwner**.

I'm trying code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53669865/1762587) in my base activity, but now, apparently because I've loaded multiple activities my events are firing multiple times...once for each Activity/Listener.

How can I implement this so that there is only one listener but all Activities have access to the application events?  I considered using the Application class as the single listener, but I'm not sure how I can then link into those events or pass that information back to my various Activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `Application` class to listen to lifecyle events, `BaseActivity` can register with the `Application` class as current `Activity` in `onResume()`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((App)getApplication()).registerActivity(this);
}
```

The `Application` class needs fields

```
private boolean showDialog = false;
private BaseActivity currentRegisteredActivity = null;
```

then as soon as an `Activity` is registered it will be told to show the dialog if the app has been in the background up to now:

```
public void registerActivity(BaseActivity activity) {
    currentRegisteredActivity = activity;
    if(showDialog){
        activity.showInitialDialog();
        showDialog = false;
    }
}
```

The methods for observing the lifecycle events:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
public void appInResumedState(){
    showDialog = true;
    Log.d(LIFECYLE_EVENT, "appInResumedState: ");
    if(currentRegisteredActivity != null){
        currentRegisteredActivity.showInitialDialog();
        showDialog = false;
    }
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
public void appInPausedState(){
    showDialog = false;
    Log.d("LIFECYLE_EVENT", "appInPausedState: ");
    currentRegisteredActivity = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this?

Have your activities (or fragments) implement a common interface that your Application will keep a reference to and call on during lifecycle events.

```
class MyApplication : Application(), LifeCycleObserver {
  private var delegate: LifeCycleDelegate? = null

  // ... Initialization code for LifeCycle

  fun updateCurrentDelegate(delegate: LifeCycleDelegate) {
   currentActivity = delegate
  }

  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
  fun appInResumeState() {
      delegate.onResumeCalled()
  }
}
```

Knowing when to set the variable for the current delegate might be tricky.

This is all just guessing, though. I've only messed with `LifeCycleOwner` and `LifeCycleObserver` from an Activity so far. I hope this helps!