# Lifecycle OnLifecycleEvent is deprecated

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lifecycle

After updating `lifecycle` library to 2.4.0 Android studio marked all Lifecycle events as deprecated.

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
fun create() {
    tts = TextToSpeech(context, this)
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
fun stopTTS() {
    tts?.stop()
}
```

Is there any equivalent replacement such as `DefaultLifecycleObserver` ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's deprecated because they now expect you to use Java 8 and implement the interface DefaultLifecycleObserver. Since Java 8 allows interfaces to have default implementations, they defined DefaultLifecycleObserver with empty implementations of all the methods so you only need to override the ones you use.

The old way of marking functions with `@OnLifecycleEvent` was a crutch for pre-Java 8 projects. This was the only way to allow a class to selectively choose which lifecycle events it cared about. The alternative would have been to force those classes to override all the lifecycle interface methods, even if leaving them empty.*

In your case, change your class to implement DefaultLifecycleObserver and change your functions to override the applicable functions of DefaultLifecycleObserver. If your project isn't using Java 8 yet, you need to update your Gradle build files. Put these in the `android` block in your module's `build.gradle`:

```groovy
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

---

*Note: Well, they could have used the old Java pattern of providing an interface Adapter class that has open, empty implementations of each interface function. The downside with this approach, though, is that the listener must be solely a listener. But I think that should usually be the case anyway if you care about encapsulation.

Comment: will it work with java 11 ?

Comment: Yes, Java 8 is a *minimum* requirement. New Java versions are always backwards compatible with all previous features.

Answer (score 44):

Your class must implement DefaultLifecycleObserver like so

```
public class MyFavoriteClass implements DefaultLifecycleObserver
```

Then implement the methods needed (Android Studio: ALT + i)

```
@Override
public void onResume(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
    methodRunsAtOnResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
    myFavoriteOnDestroyMethod();
}
```

In your activity or fragment add this to onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyOtherClass clazz = new MyOtherClass();
    getLifecycle().addObserver(clazz);
}
```

To implement it more correctly create your own observer class, pass the object you like to observe to it. Nice article about it is https://medium.com/@MinaSamy/android-architecture-components-lifecycle-433ace1ec05d

Comment: This is the correct answer to the main question according to the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lco - not the one marked as a correct in this thread.

Comment: @PiotrWittchen, my answer is short on detail, but the first sentence of the third paragraph is describing what is explained in detail here.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply replace the deprecated `@OnLifecycleEvent` with `DefaultLifecycleObserver` as you can see in the following example:

Old code:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
fun onCreate() {
    // your code
}
```

New code:

```
override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onCreate(owner)
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to keep track of the current `Activity`'s lifecycle, you can use the `LifecycleEventObserver` class.
First, create a callback,

```kotlin
private val lifecycleEventObserver = LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
    if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME ) {
        Log.e( "APP" , "resumed" )
    }
    else if ( event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE ) {
        Log.e( "APP" , "paused" )
    }
}
```

Attach the callback in the `onCreate` method of the `Activity` using `lifecycle.add( Observer )` method,

```kotlin
lifecycle.addObserver( lifecycleEventObserver )
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, Inherit the class from `LifecycleEventObserver`

Then in the `init` block or `onCreate` add this line:

```
lifecycle.addObserver(this)
```

or if you are working in non-activity/fragment class then add this instead:

```
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
```

Then override `onStateChanged` function:

```
override fun onStateChanged(source: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) {
    when(event){
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> TODO()
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> TODO()
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> TODO()
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> TODO()
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> TODO()
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> TODO()
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_ANY -> TODO()
    }
}
```

Also, if you have implemented `androidx-startup` in manifest then change that code to this otherwise `LifecycleEventObserver` won't call:

```
<provider
         android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
         android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
         android:exported="false"
         tools:node="merge">

<!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components then define it in this block-->
         
</provider>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create this function to use `DefaultLifecycleObserver` and call it in `onCreate`() lifecycle callback of an `Activity`

```kotlin
    private fun addDefaultLifeCycleObserver() {
        val defaultLifecycleObserver = object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                super.onCreate(owner)
                Log.d("Main", "DefaultLifecycleObserver - onCreate")
            }
        }
        lifecycle.addObserver(defaultLifecycleObserver)
    }
```