# @OnLifecycleEvent Deprecated issue in android studio

Tags: android, lifecycle, billing

Hi can anyone please solve the issue have added billing lifecycle events in android component lifecycle events but i am getting annotation getting deprecated
library i am using

> def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
> implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
> implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
> annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

I am using google billing version as

> implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0"
> my class

```
public class BillingClientLifecycle implements DefaultLifecycleObserver, PurchasesUpdatedListener,
> BillingClientStateListener, SkuDetailsResponseListener{
>  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
> public void create() {
> Log.d(TAG, "ON_CREATE");
> Create a new BillingClient in onCreate().
> Since the BillingClient can only be used once, we need to create a new instance
> after ending the previous connection to the Google Play Store in onDestroy().
> billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(app)
>                 .setListener(this)
>                 .enablePendingPurchases() // Not used for subscriptions.
>                 .build();
> SharedPreferences  msharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app);
> editor = msharedPreferences.edit();
> if (!billingClient.isReady()) {
> Log.d(TAG, "BillingClient: Start connection...");
> billingClient.startConnection(this);
>         }
>     }
> }
>
```

after subscription expires the billing lifecycle not calling onCreate method which is causing unlocking features

`I exteneded LifecycleObserver class  which is not working properly`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70384129/7874746

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72271549/7874746