# How to get running package names for Android L

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, activity-manager

So we all know that the getRecentTasks() and getRunningTasks() on ActivityManager are now deprecated and will return a reduced result set on Android L and higher devices.

[Alternative to getRunningTasks in Android L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400469/alternative-to-getrunningtasks-in-android-l)

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=29

However, I am trying to find a solution to keep my App Locker app alive on Android L. I need the package name of the top Activity in order to show the lock screen when the users opens/launches the locked app.

It is very similar to this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en

Currently I am using this code:

```
  ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager
                .getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getPackageName();
```

But it won't work in Android L, so I am not sure what exactly to do...

How can I implement something like this in Android L?

Comment: Isn't the whole reason they removed this to prevent people from writing apps which interfere with others, ie, **to stop exactly what you are trying to do**?

Comment: Ty this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400469/alternative-to-getrunningtasks-in-android-l

Comment: please see my answer in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27140347/847478

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent in Android 5.0: it is not possible to get the top most activity, nor is it possible get any callback when a new application/activity is launched in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

please refer this  [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581311/android-m-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-package-namefrom-a-ser/33828821#33828821)

i hope it will helpful to you, in my project it work. thanks.

Comment: How to get class name to get topactivity

Comment: you can not get the top activity class name in Android L but try this code, it work in my project perfectly..  String mClassName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName(); @muku

Comment: getRunningTasks(1) is deprecated ,i think so it doesnt work in Android L

Answer (score -2):

Try this line of code for Android L

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService (Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

String packageName = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
```

and please note that this works only for Lollipop devices .. If you want any platform support then add the following code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
String packageName = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
}
else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
String packageName =  ProcessManager.getRunningForegroundApps(getApplicationContext()).get(0).getPackageName();
}
else
{
String packageName = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

}
```