# How to find whether activity is last activity in stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack, activity-manager

I am opening a link in my app and once back is pressed I want to show HomePage to retain user for some more time. I have been trying to acheive this but unable to do so. I get homeLauncher activity as my top as well as baseActivity.

DeepLink Tap > Open desired Activity > user presses back button > Check if its last activity but not homeActivity > If yes, Navigate user to homeActivity.

Tried following code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(10);

if(taskList.get(0).numActivities == 1 && taskList.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().equals(this.getClass().getName())){
  //// This is last activity
}
else{
    //// There are more activities in stack
}

super.onBackPressed();
}
```

[image: Android Studio Evalation]

I have also tried isTaskRoot but result is same. It doesn't give right answer.Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975811/how-to-check-if-an-activity-is-the-last-one-in-the-activity-stack-for-an-applica

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar : Have a look on image name of my topActivity is not same as last activity. It shows launcher activity as topActivity. This only happens when I come from deeplinks. This problem is particular to deeplinks. So I alreadt tried the same but it didn't worked out for me.

Comment: You are getting the activity count from the first task in tasklist(may not be the task for your activity if started in a new task)

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581311/android-m-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-package-namefrom-a-ser/33828821#33828821

Comment: you **could** (if everything else fails), maintain this stack yourself with a little bit of work. Add a stack in your `Application` class (supposing you do have your own `Application` class) and every time on the `onCreate` of your activities (all of them), put the activity to that stack in the application and on the `onDestroy()`, pop them. This way you can check the status of the live activities.

Answer (score 5):

Use isTaskRoot() method. (From a  [h9kdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775071/h9kdroid) comment - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975811/how-to-check-if-an-activity-is-the-last-one-in-the-activity-stack-for-an-applica))

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
   List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(10);

   if(isTaskRoot()){
     //// This is last activity
   } else{
     //// There are more activities in stack
   }

   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: isTaskRoot returns true for the _first_ activity in the stack: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#isTaskRoot%28%29

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the `ActivityManager` it keeps track of which activity is and is not here is a piece of code I stumbled on that I use always:

```
ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );

List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(10);

if(taskList.get(0).numActivities == 1 &&
 taskList.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().equals(this.getClass().getName())) {
Log.i(TAG, "This is last activity in the stack");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting From **[ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html)**

> Information you can retrieve about a particular task that is currently
>   "running" in the system. Note that a running task does not mean the
>   given task actually has a process it is actively running in; it simply
>   means that the user has gone to it and never closed it, but currently
>   the system may have killed its process and is only holding on to its
>   last state in order to restart it when the user returns.

```
                   String getLastOpenClass ;// Global 

                    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
                    componentInfo.getPackageName();
                    getLastOpenClass=taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
                    if(getLastOpenClass.equals("Your_Class_Name"))
                    {

                    }else{

                    }
```

Give permission 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />`

The **ActivityManager** keeps a record of the ***runnings task*** and the *topmost* task .

```
       ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
       List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(10);

      if(taskList.get(0).numActivities == 1 && taskList.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().equals(this.getClass().getName()))
      {
        Log.i(TAG, "This is Last activity in the stack");
      }
```

Courtesy [How to check if an activity is the last one in the activity stack for an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975811/how-to-check-if-an-activity-is-the-last-one-in-the-activity-stack-for-an-applica)

Please Check **[How can I get the current foreground activity package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581311/android-m-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-package-namefrom-a-ser)**

> http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274874/see-android-recent-task-executed-by-the-user

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the below solution will only work on API14+.

Create a custom application class;

```
public class App extends Application {

    private int created;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Callbacks());
    }

    public int getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    private class Callbacks implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            created++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
            created--;
        }
    }
}
```

Register it in your AndroidManifest.xml in the application element;

```
<application name=".App"/>
```

And in your activity opened through a deep link use the following piece of code;

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (((App) getApplicationContext()).getCreated() == 1) {
        // start your home activity
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

I wrote this off the top of my head so I haven't had a chance to test it, but theoretically it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Specify parent activity for desired Activity, like :

```
<activity
    android:name=".DesiredActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.packagename.HomePage" >
    <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.packagename.HomePage" />
</activity>
```

With the parent activity declared, you can use the NavUtils APIs to
synthesize a new back stack by identifying which activity is the
appropriate parent for each activity.

override onBackPressed as :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        startActivity(intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Android developer's site has a very good resource for same problem. Please refer to link http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#SynthesizeBackStack