# Is there an alternative for getRunningTask API

Tags: android

I was using getRunningTask API in one of my application to find the Foreground application. This API has been deprecated since Lollipop. After this deprecation, I preferred getRunningAppProcess API along with Importance_Foreground. I also ruled out REASON_SERVICE and REASON_PROVIDER from this list. I filtered out the system applications based on a logic, which worked perfectly. The problem is that, If Application A is on foreground, I get Application B as a spike. So, this approach is currently questionable. Is there any  other alternative to the getRunningTask API?? Or am I missing any simple thing in the current approach. Please help guys.

Comment: This would really depend on your purpose for the information.  If it's a legitimate one there are probably alternatives, but they would depend on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How can I get the current foreground activity (from a service)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/android-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-from-a-service)

Comment: I'm voting to close this since there are way too many questions about this on StackOverflow, and the original question already covers the techniques in this question.

Answer (score 30):

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400469/alternative-to-getrunningtasks-in-android-l)

```
String getTopPackage(){
    long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService("usagestats");
    List<UsageStats> usageStats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST, ts-1000, ts);
    if (usageStats == null || usageStats.size() == 0) {
        return NONE_PKG;
    }
    Collections.sort(usageStats, mRecentComp);
    return usageStats.get(0).getPackageName();
}
```

This is the `mRecentComp`:

```
static class RecentUseComparator implements Comparator<UsageStats> {

    @Override
    public int compare(UsageStats lhs, UsageStats rhs) {
        return (lhs.getLastTimeUsed() > rhs.getLastTimeUsed()) ? -1 : (lhs.getLastTimeUsed() == rhs.getLastTimeUsed()) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

This permission is needed:

```
<uses-permission xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

And you will need user authorization to request the stats, use this to direct the user to the settings page:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

And you can check if you already have permission like this:

```
public static boolean needPermissionForBlocking(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
        return  (mode != AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. All of the things mentioned works like a charm. But one more thing, can I use any kind of Content Observer on this to know when the user turns it off or on? I'll accept the answer soon after I get response for this.

Comment: I guess you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896746/android-is-there-a-broadcast-action-for-volume-changes.

Comment: If that doesn't work you could use the needPermission function in my answer to check if it's on.

Comment: i tried the way u mentioned @gaston but the list always is empty. The permission in manifest, setting enabled from user , its all done but the list is still empty. Device used is Nexus 7 and android version is  5.0.1

Comment: on changing "ts-1000" to "ts-4000" the list started to fill up

Comment: It's documented that there may not be a system activity to handle the `Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS` intent.  Samsung and LG are among the manufacturers who have removed this activity from their Lollipop builds, so this solution will never work on their devices.

Comment: It's working on samsung for sure, I haven't tested it on an LG device.

Comment: thanks for 'tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"'. otherwise 'Permission is only granted to system apps' compile error occur.

Comment: You need an interval of at least a day to get the lists. Use following code to get the list `List<UsageStats> usageStats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST, ts - 86400000, ts);`  86400000 = (60*60*24*1000)

Answer (score 3):

Get the list of `RunningAppProcessInfo` by `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`.
Choose the `RuningAppProcessInfo` with whose `importance` == `RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND` and whose `processState` == `ActivityManager.START_TASK_TO_FRONT`.
(The former is easy, the latter is difficult because the reflection is necessary)

See my answer for this question [getRunningTasks doesn't work in Android L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625936/getrunningtasks-doesnt-work-in-android-l/28277427#28277427)

Comment: Doesn't work in Android M pre-release, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, it is. We should find new approach.