# Best way to determine to current foreground application, Android

Tags: android

This question has been answered elsewhere but all solutions use ".getRunningTask()", which has been depreciated in the most recent API.  I am trying to make an app that allows people to monitor their phone use and need to know when an app come to the foreground and when the foreground app changes.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you have a look at this answer you will find what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27304318/1173391