# Android 5.0+ getRunningTasks is deprecated

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, deprecated, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have gone through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag/32366476#32366476) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714285/is-there-an-alternative-for-getrunningtask-api/27304318#27304318). But with the help of this [library](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses) i can now get the list of foreground tasks using following code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { //For versions less than lollipop
            ActivityManager am = ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(5);
            top = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
            Log.v(TAG, "top app = " + top);
        }else{ //For versions Lollipop and above
            List<AndroidAppProcess> processes = ProcessManager.getRunningForegroundApps(getApplicationContext());
            Collections.sort(processes, new ProcessManager.ProcessComparator());
            for (AndroidAppProcess process : processes) {
                if (process.foreground) {
                    top =process.name;
                    Log.v(TAG,top);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here, for Android 5.0+, i get all running foreground process but i'm unable to conclude which app is the top app.

Output for above code (for else condition)

```
com.android.vending
com.google.android.gms
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
com.google.android.videos
com.test1
com.naag.testing
com.example.android.gettask
```

Here my top app is `com.google.android.videos`

Now how to decide `com.google.android.videos` is the top app from the above list programmatically?

How does applocker (or similar to applocker) app works on 5.0+? 
Hope someone helps which will be helpful for someone.

Comment: You need to set criteria as to what makes a Process Top process, like the CPU, Memory usage, etc., I guess you'll have to iterate through the `statm` provided by each of the processes to find that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is an update. Tested in 5.0 and 5.1.1 device. Working perfectly.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { //For versions less than lollipop
            ActivityManager am = ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(5);
            top = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
            Log.v(TAG, "top app = " + top);
        }else{ //For versions Lollipop and above
            List<AndroidAppProcess> processes = ProcessManager.getRunningForegroundApps(getApplicationContext());
            Collections.sort(processes, new ProcessManager.ProcessComparator());
            for (int i = 0; i <=processes.size()-1 ; i++) {
                if(processes.get(i).name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google.android.gms")) { //always the package name above/below this package is the top app
                    if ((i+1)<=processes.size()-1) { //If processes.get(i+1) available, then that app is the top app
                        top = processes.get(i + 1).name;
                    } else if (i!=0) { //If the last package name is "com.google.android.gms" then the package name above this is the top app
                        top = processes.get(i - 1).name;
                    } else{
                        if (i == processes.size()-1) { //If only one package name available
                            top = processes.get(i).name;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.v(TAG, "top app = " + top);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks to this [library](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses)

Now i'm able to get foreground task in Android 5.0+

Comment: yes.. its working..But I think no need  **if(processes.get(i).name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google.android.gms")) {** this condition..

Comment: This code doesn't do the work. It doesn't bring the top most application from foreground. ProcessManager.ProcessComparator just does this: p1.name.compareToIgnoreCase(p2.name); It compares strings and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The "apps with usage accesse" feature sometimes can meet your needs