# How to display lock activity quickly when user click on another installed application in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I'm trying to open lock activity while opening another installed app. Its working fine. Lock activity does open, but it opens after another application launches. So how to open lock activity before another application launches? If anyone have solution then help me.Through searching i search code that [get foreground task in android 5.0 +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918528/android-5-0-getrunningtasks-is-deprecated)

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    try {
        arrayList.clear();
        Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getAll();
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                arrayList.add(cursor.getString(2));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;
        }
        if (arrayList.size() == 0) {
            activity = this.context.getPackageName().toString();
        } else {
            activity = arrayList.get(0).toString();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { //For versions less than lollipop
            ActivityManager am = ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(5);
            top = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
            Log.v(TAG, "top from Receiver app = " + top);
            for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo info : taskInfo) {
                if (info.topActivity.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(activity)) {
                    intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Lock_Screen.class);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        } else { //For versions Lollipop and above
            List<AndroidAppProcess> processes = ProcessManager.getRunningForegroundApps(context.getApplicationContext());
            Collections.sort(processes, new ProcessManager.ProcessComparator());
            for (int i = 0; i <= processes.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (!processes.get(i).name.isEmpty()) {
                    top = processes.get(i).name;

                    Log.e(TAG, "top from Receiver app=" + top);
                    if (processes.get(i).name.equalsIgnoreCase(activity)) {
                        intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Lock_Screen.class);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(intent);

                    }

                }
                if (processes.get(i).name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google.android.youtube")) { //always the package name above/below this package is the top app
                    if ((i + 1) <= processes.size() - 1) { //If processes.get(i+1) available, then that app is the top app
                        top = processes.get(i + 1).name;
                    } else if (i != 0) { //If the last package name is "com.google.android.gms" then the package name above this is the top app
                        top = processes.get(i - 1).name;
                    } else {
                        if (i == processes.size() - 1) { //If only one package name available
                            top = processes.get(i).name;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.v(TAG, "top app from Receiver = " + top);
                }
            }
        }
     //   context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Service_1.class));
        databaseHelper.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be because you are opening lock activity after receiving launch event of other app.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion..:)