# getAppTask returning empty list in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-manager

I'm trying to get my app's task info with answered mentioned here-

[ActivityManager.getRunningTasks is deprecated android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156313/activitymanager-getrunningtasks-is-deprecated-android)

I'm not able to figure out any issue. Can anyone help on this? Any permission I need to add?

Comment: Refer This Link Dear,[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918528/android-5-0-getrunningtasks-is-deprecated)

Comment: This is using library. I want without lib.