# move app from background to foreground using its package name and `moveTaskToFront()` method in android

Tags: android

In my app I want to bring the background app to foreground by knowing its package name. I know it can be done using `moveTaskToFront()` method but I don't know how to implement it.I am currently testing it on Lollipop android version.Can anyone know the solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> rt = am.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < rt.size(); i++) 
    {
           // bring to front
           if (rt.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString().indexOf("yourproject") > -1) {                     
              am.moveTaskToFront(rt.get(i).id, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);
           }
    }
```

Inside your manifest add :

```
<!--User Permissions-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```

Comment: If you are only interested in top activity of **your own app**: you can use `getAppTasks()`.
Also look on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26451064/6028746

Comment: No,I want to move the background apps to foreground using its package name

Comment: Starting Android L getRunningTasks() can't give us the task information.

Answer (score 0):

I racked my brains for a few days trying to do the same without success until I tried `Intent`. Once you know the name of the package, and you know that it is in the background `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` .

The code will look more or less like this:

```
PackageManager pck = getPackageManager();
Intent i = pck.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.airdatatech.alibrowser");
if (pck != null && i != null) {      

      i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
      startActivity(i);

}
```

You will need to add the permission to the Manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />`