# how to get top activity info in Android Lollipop(5.0) and Above os versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I Am Developing an App where I need to recognise the current running app on top, so I have tried with below code

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    
    // get the info from the currently running task
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    
    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    if(!componentInfo.getPackageName().equals("your.package.name"))
    {
        //Do your stuff
    }
```

But it's not working on Android Lollipop(5.0) and above os version, It's not returning the current running app informations.

please help if any one have any idea to do so on android lollipop(5.0) and above os versions.

Comment: Refer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400469/alternative-to-getrunningtasks-in-android-l

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `UsageStatsManager` class to achieve this. It requires `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`. But it is mentioned as below in the [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html).

> NOTE: This API requires the permission android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.

This means the user must also enable access for this app through Settings > Security > Apps with usage access.

Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#System) for more details.