# Android: Listen for starting applications

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to listen for starting applications/activities.
I guess many of You know the application "Tasker" which achieves exactly that. If a chosen applications gets launched, a specific task starts.

Now I wonder how to achieve that? I could start a Service, but which method should I use?

I noticed that Tasker asks for a permission before using this method. The application redirects me to the Accessibility Settings tab where I can enable Tasker with the notification: "Tasker wants permission to: Monitor your actions - Allows TalkBack to know when you are using an app"

Any suggestions?

**Edit**:

I found out that an AccessibilityService is used. Now my problem is, how do I specify all installed packages to this Service? I know that it's possible to specify packages one by one but how do I select all?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [getRunningTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)) Method

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
            .getPackageName();
```

**Note** This method was deprecated in API level 21. you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27140347/3758898) also.