# What is the appropriate alternate to ActivityManager.getRunningTasks method for android lollipop?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi, kiosk-mode

I have a kiosk kind of app from which I am opening the WiFi Activity. As suggested in the other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625936/getrunningtasks-doesnt-work-in-android-l)  , I have tried using the IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND to my use, but in vain.

When I open the WifiSettings from my app using

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

This opens the Wifi Settings Activity, and at this time there is only 1 running process of my app and it's importance is IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE. I want to find a way of detecting the top Wifi Settings activity.

In short, Wifi Settings is being added to the same process. But am not able to get the top activity using

```
ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()
```

OR

```
ActivityManager.getAppTasks()
```

Kindly help.Thanks in advance.