# How to detect current foreground app when foreground service is running

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on an AppLock which includes service that detects current foreground app but the problem is the service keeps returning the AppLock itself as the current foreground app even after I minimize it or close the AppLock. Is there a way to fix this?

I'm aware of other similar questions have been answered but I don't see anyone else having the same problem as me as far as I can see.

Below is the code I'm using to detect the foreground app

```
public String getForegroundApp() {

    String currentApp = "NULL";
    UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);
    if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
        SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
        for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
            mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
        }
        if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
            currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
        }
    }
    else {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        currentApp = tasks.get(0).processName;
    }

    return currentApp;
}
```

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(foreapp.equals(lockedApp)){
        Intent intentp3=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PasswordPage3.class);
        intentp3.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intentp3);
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The receiver I'm using to start the service:

```
public class RestartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent lol) {
        Log.i("running in the back","restarting");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Note: foreapp and lockedApp are both String variables

The String that currentApp returns are constantly com.example.apptest3 which is the package name that I'm working on.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this will work.  queryUsageStats doesn't promise that its results are sorted, and doesn't promise the app is the foreground app.  getRunningAppProcesses, your backup call, also returns both foreground and background apps with no promises of order.

Comment: Can you suggest a way that returns the currently opened app only?

Comment: I tried a lot of ways on getting the foreground app but they are still producing the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is no more. I solved the problem using the answer provided by Tarun Sharma in one of the previous questions, if anyone is facing the same problem as me, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag).

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the top activity since Android L, but there's a workaround using **ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo**'s **importance** to get when an app is launched by the user, [checkout these previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625936/getrunningtasks-doesnt-work-in-android-l).

Comment: Can you specify the solution that is working for you? I went to that link but none of them is working for me

Comment: They are either still detecting the applock only after the applock being minimized or unable to detect anything after minimizing the applock