# Restart Accessibility Service After Crash

Tags: android, service, binding, accessibilityservice

In my Application there is a `Service` and an `AccessibilityService`. Now the `Service` is bound by the accessibility Service in order to receive information.

My `Service` periodically checks if the `AccessibilityService` is enabled, and if it is not, it sends a notification to the user that it has to enable it.

Once enabled, `AccessibilityService` starts to work. First it binds to my `Service`, and after, it begins to send information.

The problem is if `AccessibilityService` crashes. It remains enabled but there is no running instance. So my `Service` finds it enabled but actually the `AccessibilityService` is not running.

**How Check `AccessibilityService`**

```
public boolean checkAccesibilityService()
    {
        int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
        boolean accessibilityFound = false;
        try {
            accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(
                    mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
            //Log.v(TAG, "accessibilityEnabled = " + accessibilityEnabled);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
            //Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILIY IS ENABLED*** -----------------");
            String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(
                    mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
            if (settingValue != null) {

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(settingValue)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Nessun servizio abilitato!");
                    return false;
                }
                TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter splitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');
                splitter.setString(settingValue);

                while (splitter.hasNext()) {
                    String accessabilityService = splitter.next();

                    //Log.v(TAG, "-------------- > accessabilityService :: " + accessabilityService);
                    if (accessabilityService.equalsIgnoreCase(ACCESSIBILITY_SERVCE)) {
                        //Log.v(TAG, "Accessibility Service Attivato!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                Log.v(TAG, "Accesibility Service non abilitato!");
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILIY IS DISABLED***");
        }

        return accessibilityFound;

    }
```

**Q1:** Why when the `AccessibilityService` crashes does the Android OS not restart it?

**Q2:** Can I change my code to check if the `AccessibilityService` is enabled but also has a running instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why when the `AccessibilityService` crashes does the Android OS not restart it?

I don't know, but I suspect there isn't much you can do about this. I've had similar problems with `AccessibilityService`s, so I think this is normal behaviour. The best I can think of is:

- Carefully write your `AccessibilityService` code and thoroughly test it so that it doesn't contain any bugs that will cause it to crash.
- Don't do any logic in your `AccessibilityService` that you could also do in a different place. The less work your `AccessibilityService` is doing, the simpler it is, so the less likely it is to have bugs.
- Make your `AccessibilityService` code error-tolerant. Predict errors that will happen inside the service, and write code to catch them and recover from them so that the `AccessibilityService` continues running normally if possible.
- Run your `AccessibilityService` in its own process so it isn't killed when your other code crashes. Note that this might be difficult depending on how the service interacts with the rest of your code.

#### Can I change my code to check if the AccessibilityService is enabled but also has a running instance?

Yes; there are a couple of common techniques to do this. See [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android).

Comment: @v1sc3rr4k, you're welcome. I just edited the answer to also suggest putting the `AccessibilityService` in its own process so it doesn't crash when your other code crashes.

Comment: @v1sc3rr4k Is it possible to run accessibility service in a separate process?  
My service does not start when I give a process name

Comment: @Sam i need your help about the accessibility service

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the Accessibility Service programmatically just before crash occurrs in handleUncaughtException ( Application Class ) by calling disableSelf(); method
But this works on Nogout and above only.