# How to check is app in foreground from service?

Tags: android, android-service

I need to show notification to user only if application is not in foreground. Here is my public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends

```
FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if(applicationInForeground()) {
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            sendNotification(data.get("title"), data.get("detail"));
        }

    }
```

need to implement `applicationInForeground()` method

Comment: take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service

Comment: you can use Activity's lifecycle callbacks, and send broadcasts to the service when it goes to BG/FG

Comment: How many activities you are using in Application?

Comment: There are two type of message in FCM data-message(for background) and display-message(foreground). You have to use different configuration for both message to receive message in background or foreground. have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase

Comment: look at Sam answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/ 
Github project based on that answer: https://github.com/seguri/GetForegroundActivity

Comment: Solution from Google here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767617/1269737

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can control running app processes from android system service. Try this:

```
private boolean applicationInForeground() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    boolean isActivityFound = false;

    if (services.get(0).processName
            .equalsIgnoreCase(getPackageName()) && services.get(0).importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
        isActivityFound = true;
    }

    return isActivityFound;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hello, I'm Android newbie. I'm face same issue but stuck on how to import getPackageName(). Does getPackageName() coming from context? How to access context while I'm at service?

Comment: And my another question, would this code work on Android jellybean until Android oreo? Thank you

Comment: This function is not working on the Android 7.0 from the Service.

Comment: Will be better also check services.get(0).importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND

Answer (score 22):

At Google I/O 2016, I gave a talk where one of the topics was how [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) detects if your app is in the foreground.  You can use [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) for that by incrementing a counter for every activity in your app that gets started, then decrementing it for each activity that gets stopped.  If the counter is > 1, then your app is in the foreground.  The relevant part of the talk can be seen on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/AJqakuas_6g?t=28m50s).

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing that video!

Comment: @doug-stevenson why don't you expose this method in FirebaseMessagingService so that android programmers have a better life?

And more in general, why are com.google.firebase:** not opensource?

Comment: I am doing this via weakreference, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181737/4269149), what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Don't you mean counter > 0 :-)

Answer (score 20):

You can use `ProcessLifecycleOwner` from [Jetpack lifecycle components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle).

```
import androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner

class AppFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService(), DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private var isAppInForeground = false

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        isAppInForeground = true
    }

    override fun onStop(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        isAppInForeground = false
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        if (isAppInForeground) {
            // do foreground stuff on your activities
        } else {
            // send a notification
        }
    }
}
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies) how to import the necessary dependencies, since lifecycle is not part of the standard Android SDK.

Comment: for using of it  implementations of `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions` and `android.arch.lifecycle:compiler` must be added, please add it to your answer

Comment: @ZhebzhikBabich, I added a link to Android documentation.

Comment: @ekashking, it's [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.html) class, make sure you have the correct package imported in your classpath.

Comment: That's what I guessed. I think the answer should start by mentioning that first.

Comment: Well, it's part of the Jetpack support library and adding support libraries is fairly standard for Android development. I will clarify my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I just report a Kotlin version of [@bompf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823483/bompf) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55146756/3442842)

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver
import androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent
import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage

class AppFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService(), LifecycleObserver {

    private var isAppInForeground = false

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onForegroundStart() {
        isAppInForeground = true
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onForegroundStop() {
        isAppInForeground = false
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        if (isAppInForeground) {
            // do foreground stuff on your activities
        } else {
            // send a notification
        }
    }
}
```