# How to detect the active activity in a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a way that I can detect the active activity from my `BroadcastReceiver`?

Here's my code:

```
class Receiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
         // check the active activity
         // if MainActivity then ....
         // if OtherActivity then ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How can I get the current foreground activity (from a service)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/android-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-from-a-service)

Comment: Anything special you want with this? You can send a broadcast to the system, and have code in every Activity that can hear it and process the message. For those you can actually use LocalBroadcastManager

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can **keep a reference on the `Application` to the last `Activity` that passed `onResume`** (and clear it when it passes `onStop`)

In theory, you could get the `Activity` visible if that variable is not null. In practice if you have transparent Activities some things may not work properly.

Comment: Can you provide Sallie coffee pls, I tried making reference for the activity in the reviewer, but couldn't call it from the shuttle itself. Thanks