# Is there a way to get broadcast ? when user switches between apps in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, activity-manager

Is there a way to get broadcast ? When user switches between apps in android.

Comment: There is no such broadcast, you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871119/how-to-be-notified-when-foreground-top-activity-application-changes

Answer (score 0):

There is no such `Intent` which you can use Best bet would be to monitor the activity stack. As Answered in

[How to be notified when foreground (top) activity (application) changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871119/how-to-be-notified-when-foreground-top-activity-application-changes)